# TextToSpeech not working when a datepicker is opened

Tags: android, calendar, accessibility, talkback

I am trying to add some extra information in TextToSpeech(TTS) for accessibility users like when a user clicks on the calendar button, there should be TTS announcement like this is a calendar widget,user should swipe up or down to select a date.

So I added a textToSpeech code inside the onclick of the calendar button. But the TTS does not work and the talkback directly announces the date which is selected/current date.

My code structure is like : -

```
          calendarButton.onclick{ 
          if(accessibilityIsActive)
           tts.speak("This is a calendar widget.Do this... to select a date") 
           };
```

When I am in debug mode and execute step by step , tts gets executed and I could hear my text.But When in normal mode I select the button Talkback overrides this step and the focus goes to the dialog box header that is the current date and so it just tells the current date.I am using the android default calendar widget.

Is there any way I can make the TTS work and then let the talkback take back control on the  date dialog ??? I am using a nexus 5 with android OS 6.0

Answer (score 0):

Don't use TTS directly.  Post an accessibility announcement and let the Accessibility framework decide how to handle it.

```
AccessibilityEvent e = AccessibilityEvent.obtain();
e.setEventType(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT);
e.setClassName(getClass().getName());
e.setPackageName(context.getPackageName());
e.getText().add("some text");
manager.sendAccessibilityEvent(e);
```